# Use multi threading to read files/processing using Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, file, io

So I haven't really done any serious multithreading before( with the exception of the typical for-loop textbook example) so I thought I might give it a try. The task that I am trying to accomplish is the following:

1. Read an identification code from a file called `ids.txt`
2. Search for that identification code in a separate file called `sequence.txt`
3. Once identification is found, extract the string that follows the id.
4. Create an object of type `DataSequence` (which encapsulates the identification code and the extracted sequence) and add it to an ArrayList.
5. Repeat for 3000+ ids.

I have tried this the "regular" way within a single thread but the process is way too slow.How can I approach this issue in a multi-threaded fashion ?

Comment: Can you show us some code you have tried? We can't just give you the answer, we have to show you how it works.

Comment: How big are these files? Is it possible to load them into memory (particularly `sequence.txt`)? In any event, I'd strongly suggest that you profile your code to find out exactly where the time is going before taking a stab at multithreading as a solution. And if you are going that route, then you should definitely throttle the number of threads to something reasonable (e.g., 8 or 16).

Comment: All I have is the regular, single threaded approach with a for-loop. Will that be enough ?

Comment: @TedHopp 'sequence.txt' is 53.3 MBs. 'ids.txt' is 6.57 Kb. Although,other approaches are probably possible, I am also interested in learning multithreading here.

Comment: Did you come up with this task as a learning exercise for learning how to use threads, or is it more important to just solve the problem? I have a feeling most people will keep recommending doing something other than multithreading to solve this particular problem. On the other hand, it is possible to come up with a different excercise where the performance improvement due to multithreading would be more noticeable.

Comment: @Dmitri This is more of a learning exercise.

Comment: You can read millions of lines a second with `BufferedReader.readLine().` Your bottleneck lies elsewhere, probably in searching `sequence.txt`, which you should load into a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing profiling data, it's hard to know what to recommend. But as a blind guess, I'd say that repeatedly opening, searching, and closing `sequence.txt` is taking most of the time. If this is guess is accurate, then the biggest improvement (by far) would be to find a way to process `sequence.txt` only once. The easiest way to do that would be to read in the relevant information from the file into memory, building a hash map from id to the string that follows it. The entire file is only 53.3 MB, so this is an eminently reasonable approach. Then as you process `ids.txt`, you only need to look up the relevant string from the map—a very quick operation.

An alternative would be to use the `java.nio` classes to create a memory-mapped file for `sequence.txt`.

I'd be hesitant about looking to multithreading to improve what seems to be a disk-bound operation, particularly if the threads will all end up contending for access to the same file (even if it is only read access). This does not strike me as a good problem with which to learn multithreading techniques; the payoff is just not likely to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-threading could be an overkill here. try the following algorithmic approach.
1. Open the file `ids.txt` in read mode
2. Declare a HashMap for storing key-value pair
2. Loop till end of the file
2A. Read a line as a string
2B. Parse the line as id (key) and rest of the line (value) to store in the HashMap object
3. Now search using the HashMap as desired or do whatever you need with this.

Note: 2A and 2B can be put in two different tasks for two different threads in  a producer-consumer framework of design.